# White page (Error 500) in phpmyadmin after login

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, debian, fastcgi

I'm getting 500 Error when I try to connect to my phpmyadmin. The system is a Debian 8 with LAMP, PHP-FPM and Varnish.

The login view show without problems in myserver.com/phpmyadmin but when I start a new session I'm getting Error 500.

The apache log shows this:

```
FastCGI: server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi" stderr: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function __() in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/core.lib.php on line 235
```

I was checking session and phpmyadmin config files permissions but doesn't work at all.